# Is there a way to change the UI using an ActionButton

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make an app that can change the UI by reacting to the click of an action button

I made a simple app that is a sketch of what I meant:

```
Second_UI = function(id){
  
  ns = NS(id)
  
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(renderText('Hello, this has changed!'))
  )

}

Second_server = function(input,output,session){
} 

ui =
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(actionButton('change','Change UI'))
  )
  

server = function(input,output,session){
  
  observeEvent(input$change,{
    
    output$second = renderUI(Second_UI)
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I think they are better off as subsections of one ui - for example using a tablist panel (https://shiny.posit.co/r/gallery/application-layout/navlistpanel-example/) or a navbar (https://shiny.posit.co/r/gallery/application-layout/navbar-example/) - would either of those approaches achieve your aim or does it have to be action buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do, using a [`navbar`](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.0.5/navbarpage) or [`tabsepanel`](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.0/tabsetpanel) might be the way to go.

If you want to use a `actionButton` to switch between UIs you could implement something like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      uiOutput('change_ui') # the container UI
      )
  )


server = function(input,output,session){
  
  # to keep track of page selected
  page = reactiveVal(1)
  
  # swicth logic based on
  output$change_ui = renderUI({
    
    if(page() == 1){
      uiOutput('uio_1')
    }else{
      uiOutput('uio_2')
    }
    
  })
  
  # the 2 UIs
  output$uio_1 = renderUI({
    tagList(
      h1('UI 1'),
      actionButton(inputId = 'change_1',label = 'Change from ui 1 to ui 2')
    )
  })
  output$uio_2 = renderUI({
    tagList(
      h1('UI 2'),
      actionButton(inputId = 'change_2',label = 'Change from ui 2 to ui 1')
    )
  })
  
  # observers for the buttons to update page() and swicth UI
  observeEvent(input$change_1,{page(2)})
  observeEvent(input$change_2,{page(1)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```